# Reasoning to use (or not use) conda in conjunction with atom

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor, conda

I am new to using python and am still fuzzy in terms of how python 'works' in conjunction with different things you can use to use python.

Specifically: I've been working with Anaconda and Python 3 and doing things in Jupyter, but a friend introduced me to Atom which I find much more appealing and would like to start using. I don't think I will use Hydrogen, I just want to use Atom as an editor and then execute the .py files via terminal in Atom. (I have a Mac, if this makes any difference).

I don't really understand exactly how it all works yet, but I know I have conda and I've been installing packages via conda and ... accessing them through conda right? So will using Atom mess this all up?

I've seen people ask questions about linking conda to Atom, but is this an inefficient / stupid thing to do? Like is there extra utility to using conda that I should try to keep in my use of Atom? Or would it be better in the long run to just update whatever version of Python my computer / Atom would use without Anaconda, reinstall all the packages I've been working with (I don't have THAT many yet) and just get rid of Anaconda?

Basically, I just would like to know more about how this all works and what would be the best streamlined setup. Thank you in advance for explanations and recommendations :)

Comment: " So will using Atom mess this all up?" no. Atom is just a text-editor. I would stick with conda and the anaconda python distribution, especially if you are using it for the libraries that comes with it. Writing code in a text-editor and managing everything else via the terminal is pretty standard. My advice though would be to use a good terminal emulator, for mac, iterm2 is quite good. My experience with the terminal that comes with atom is not so great, personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree pretty much with what @juanpa.arrivvillaga said in his comment. Anaconda and conda are excellent packages. Anaconda comes with Spyder which is another Python editor and IDE. But if you like Atom that is fine. If you load the 'platformio-ide-terminal' package, you can use the built-in terminal to run your Atom python code. Or you can also load the 'script' package and run your codes in Atom too. Go to [this link](https://atom.io/packages) and you can download packages for Atom which adds functionality. If you have any questions feel free to leave a comment.